# C# How to check a Listbox for a string + object?

Tags: c#, search, combobox, listbox, contains

I'm trying to search for a certain number(object) in a listbox which comes together with a string in order to highlight it. In the following bit of code i override a ToString() method to contain all my objects.

```
 public override string ToString()
    {

        string reservatiestring;
        reservatiestring = "Kamer: " + roomNumber + "" + "  Op datum: " + datum + "  Aantal personen: " + personen.Count + "  Naam: " + reservatienaam;
        return reservatiestring;
    }
```

Following this I add it to my listbox in the following bit of code:

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(reservatie.ToString());
```

I now want to search for all the items in my listbox containing the same roomNumber object. To do this i tried the Contains() method with the text before it: "Kamer: " and the object which I'm looking for +comboBox1.SelectedItem. This however always fails and my code goes to the else option giving me the error message.

```
private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        Reservations reservaties = new Reservations();

        reservaties.roomnumberstring = "Kamer: " + comboBox1.SelectedValue;

        for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(("Kamer: " + comboBox1.SelectedValue)))
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
```

Please note: All my roomNumber objects are stored in the combobox, so whenever i select for example roomNumber 3 in my combobox and hit search all the items in the listbox containing "Kamer: 3" should be selected.

The roomnumberstring is a option I tried which did not work unfortunately.

```
reservaties.roomnumberstring = "Kamer: " + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Instead of adding a String to your ListBox, add the actual Instance of your Class.  It will be displayed in the ListBox using the ToString() representation.  You can cast the entries in the ListBox to your Class Type and access all of its members...

Answer (score 0):

Your override of the ToString method is wrong and won't modify anything. Try this :

```
public override string ToString(this string reservatiestring)
{

    reservatiestring = "Kamer: " + roomNumber + "" + "  Op datum: " + datum + "  Aantal personen: " + personen.Count + "  Naam: " + reservatienaam;
    return reservatiestring;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the note, ill implement it, this however does not fix my problem when i try to search for the "Kamer: " + roomNumber part.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one thing that might make your code fail. you are comparing

```
.ToLower()
```

with "Kamer", where the "K" isn´t in lowercase

Comment: Also of course the string: "reservatiestring" contains more of non-lowercase characters that won´t be found in the comparison

Comment: This did fix the reason why it went to my error message continiously thanky you. However all my items in the listbox containing the number i selected in the combobox tend to be selected now instead of only the items containing the specific Kamer + combobox1.selecteditem. So if i search for example 2 now in the combobox all the items containing 2 in the date now get selected aswell instead of only the items containing "Kamer: 2"

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the "if" line and check what the comboBox.SelectedValue is and compare it to the value of "i", do this for each loop through the items and compare them to see why "i" is true everytime when comparing to the selected value

Comment: Sorry if I am not to better help right now, I have no developer tools where I am.. just trying to push you in the right direction, hope it helps